# android crossword game

Tags: android

maybe this sounds silly...
but as an amateur android developer, i want to know the basic idea and concepts for making crossword game in android.
we provide a box full with column, row, and random alphabet for the user and they just gonna gesture the characters that resemble a word....

cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crossword.

- Create a grid of XbyX.
- Define your answers in an array.
- Need some algorithm to fit the words into the grid (maths not programming).
- Have some type of mapping from this array to the grid.
- Draw the grid. (Draw natively with NDK or use Layouts your choice)
- Black out the  unused squares.
- Allow each square clickable to bring up the keyboard.
- Compare a filled word length with its responding array word.
- Win / Lose.

Is this how basic you wanted to go?

Comment: hi! actually it's a word search game not crossword game(sorry :p), but your method works too! :D here is the screenshot http://stat001.ameba.jp/user_images/20110404/18/drikvy/e7/4a/p/o0332047011145405137.png , now i'm facing new problem. how to block the grid with certain drawable or just simple square in order to select the word? i really have no idea about this, i've try 2d drawing tutorial with canvas, but it doesn't work in a xml layout. you can look at my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536447/how-to-use-draw-canvas-to-select-words-from-gridviewword-search-game